# Существует ли интерактивный ярлык папки в Windows?

Tags: windows, файловый-ввод-вывод

Дано:
Windows 7,  Папка в Моих Документах, Папка на диске D:

В папку в МД пишутся и читаются файлы программой. 
В самом ПО путь сменить нельзя, он железен.

Из-за большого кол-во файлов, естественно, диск C:\ заполняется полностью.

Задача:
Организовать запись и чтение файлов в папку `D:\folder`, чтобы путь папки в Моих Документах читался как зеркало.

Естественно, если просто в путь подсунуть ярлык имени папки 1в1 из `D:\folder`, - не срабатывает.

Что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать создать симлинк на другой диск, где места много:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\имя_пользователя\Мои документы\Название_папки" "d:\Путь\Название_папки"
```

Теперь любая программа, пишущая что-либо в вашу папку, будет писать эти данные в d:\Путь\Название_папки

P.S. У нас примерно так (правда, симлинки на файлы, не на папки, то есть mklink без ключа /D) работают базы данных с огромными массивами данных.

Comment: Не совсем любая, но в большинстве случаев срабатывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы имеете в виду те, которые оперируют всё ещё с именами 8.3?

Comment: Неа, те, которые удаляют символьную ссылку и создают вместо неё новую папку. Некоторые инсталляторы таким точно грешат, вроде ещё у каких-то программ встречал. Ну и nodejs считает, что символьная ссылка - это не каталог: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD7DT.png

Comment: Кстати, в этом плане ссылки на файлы вроде отличаются - они неоличимы от файлов.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Я так профили пользователей переношу, чтобы могли сваливать на рабочий стол всё что угодно.